# Git failed with fatal error, Could not resolve proxy:2

Tags: git, visual-studio, cloning

While cloning a repository in Visual Studio 2019, I get this error:

> Git failed with a fatal error, Unable to connect to dev.azure.com

Then I tried Git bash Command `git config --global Http.proxy http://domain:PWD@server:port` which in turn gave me this error:

> Git failed with a fatal error, unable to resolve proxy:2

I have also tried `git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Comment: Maybe set the proxy without `http://`?

Comment: I have set the proxy. But it is showing could not resolve proxy: 2

Comment: With or without `http://`?

Comment: Are you sure you configured the correct server/port?

Comment: Yes. I have configure the correct server with http

Comment: Do you know what does in mean by proxy: 2

Comment: Is your servername `proxy` and the port `2`?

Comment: No, Its a proxy4 and port 8080

Comment: It is looking for `proxy:2`...